# Which one sentence is correct and why?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, grammaticality, tense-agreement

> 1. When I commits mistake on any topic then always I learn by my mistake.
> 2. When I do mistake on any topic then always I learn by my mistake.

.

As per my understanding both are having same meaning but some people are not agreed with my perception. So please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these are wrong -- we don't use "do" or "commit" with mistake, we use "make". Repeating "mistake" also makes the sentence feel unnatural, since it's already implied by the former part of the sentence. I'm not sure what you mean by "topic" here, so I'm going to guess it means "situation".

As such, it seems like what you actually want is:

> I always learn from my mistakes, no matter the situation.

Comment: +1. You didn't mention this specifically, but it's worth emphasizing down here: the preposition of choice in this context is usually _from_. That is, we usually learn _from_ our mistakes, not _by_ our mistakes. We can discover something _by mistake_, if we stumble into it accidentally, but we learn _from_ our mistakes when we gain wisdom through the experience.

Comment: You can also say "if I make a mistake, I always learn from it." (just to use similar word order as TC did)

Comment: You CAN say "When I commit a mistake."  It is just not a very common thing to do.  The problem is that "I commits" is NOT correct - It would be "I commit..."  It is more common to say "When I commit an error., or When I commit errors".  You can say "He/She/It commits", just NOT "I commits."

Comment: @Msfolly At least to me as a BrE speaker to "commit a mistake" sounds highly unnatural if not erroneous. "Commit" usually only applies to *intentional* actions ("commit a crime" for example).

Comment: @Chris Down   Yes, it WOULD be highly unusual, but it would not be incorrect.   English can be very accommodating...